# No module named wx on Debian (jessie) Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, debian, wxpython, wxwidgets

Tried `apt-get install python-wxtools`, which succeeds.

When I try `import wx` though, I get `ImportError: No module named wx`.

Really confused as to why this fails as that's what the directions say to do. Not sure if this is related, but it also installs v3.0 (which I thought was the version for Phoenix/Python3) while being dependent on Python 2.7...

For what it's worth this is off the `python:2.7` Docker image